# Can the macports doc folder be safely removed?

Tags: macports

My `/opt/local/share/doc` folder is more than 1GB. Since I'm never using the offline documentation of any installed port, I would like to reclaim the disk space. Can I simply delete the folder?

Comment: Do you remove inactive ports? This will save you a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you can live without documentation and configuration examples.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid building the doc at all?

Comment: Not in general, no.